# Android Studio errors

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio and I am finding it interesting as compared to Eclipse. When I run an application it runs, but after this and even when starting Android Studio again, it has errors of all classes imported. It says it cannot recognize the objects.

as follows:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;  //Bundle, Menu and MenuItem are underlined an indication of error

import com.android.volley.*; //volley imports shows correctly


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    RequestQueue queue;
    Request request;
```

yet when I rebuild the following is the message:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

You should copy/paste all of the import code into your comment. Also, you might want to post your build.gradle file as well (but it sounds like you may just have a syntax error in the imports).

/sorry to post this as an answer but I don't have the rep to comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project first and

[image]

Sync Project with Gradle Files ;)

[image]

Comment: Even after cleaning and syncing the problem persists @Emmanuel Francis  Narvas